# R Shiny : how to use several checkboxInput values as combination?

Tags: r

I am new to R, so I figure there is probably an easy way to do this. I searched here on Stack Overflow and couldn’t find a similar question, so I apologize if I missed it.

I have 9 checkboxInputs in my ui.R, numbered from "1" to "9". The values are in character format.
If I check boxes "3" and "9", the value in the table is "39".
If I check boxes "4", "6", "8" and "9", the value to serach in the table is "4689". There are a lot of combinations.
So, I would like to know how can I concatenate all values from the checked boxes, in reactive environment, to search the right combination in a data frame ? I think it's something too complicated for a newbie as me. I have to get more experience.
Thank you very much for setting me on the right path.

Comment: if you're using `checkboxGroupInput`, `paste(input$mycheckboxes, collapse = '')` on the server side should be what you're after. But this isn't really a shiny question.

Comment: Thank you for helping Shape, I managed to get what I wanted. And you're right, there's nothing on Shiny in my question, apologize, I have edited it. Thank you again.